# A separate login react app because the HTML code which emebed it is too different from the HTML code around the main app?

Tags: reactjs

I'm building a react app, with some pages (with bootstrap) and a login page.

The login page has a different "template" than all other pages (it is often the case in web apps)

You can see screenshot.

The login page :

[image]

The page when user is logged.

[image]

Th react app should be displayed  in the "content" block, because most of common html code is around it.

But what the about the login page ?

Or I do this :

```
<div id = "app"></div>
```

And then all the HTML around the my react components will be place in the "render" function ?

I think the best should be 2 separate html pages, login.html and index.html, with 2 separate react app?

Thanks